# Handle function implicitly accounting for independent variables

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, integral

I have that

```
clc, clear all, close all
tic
k1 =  1E-02:0.1:1E+02;
k2 =  1E-02:0.1:1E+02;
k3 =  1E-02:0.1:1E+02;
k = sqrt(k1.^2+k2.^2+k3.^2);
c = 1.476;
gamma = 3.9;
colors = {'b'};
Ek = (1.453*k.^4)./((1 + k.^2).^(17/6));
E = @(k) (1.453*k.^4)./((1 + k.^2).^(17/6));
E_int = zeros(1,numel(k));
E_int(1) = 1.5;

for i = 2:numel(k)
    if k(i) < 400
        E_int(i) = E_int(i-1) - integral(E,k(i-1),k(i));
    elseif k(i) > 400
        E_int(i) = 2.180/(k(i)^(2/3));
    end %end if
end %end i


beta = (c*gamma)./(k.*sqrt(E_int));
figure
plot(k,beta,colors{1})

count = 0;
%F_11 = zeros(1,numel(k1));
F_33 = zeros(1,numel(k1));
```

Afterwards, I should calculate F_33 as

```
for i = 1:numel(k1)   
    count = count + 1;    
    phi_33 = @(k2,k3) (1.453./(4.*pi)).*(((k1(i)^2+k2.^2+(k3 + beta(i).*k1(i)).^2).^2)./((k1(i)^2+k2.^2+k3.^2).^2)).*((k1(i)^2+k2.^2)./((1+k1(i)^2+k2.^2+(k3+beta(i).*k1(i)).^2).^(17/6)));
    F_33(count) = 4*integral2(phi_33,0,1000,0,1000);    
end
```

Now let's come to my question. I know from a paper that:

```
k = sqrt(k1.^2+k2.^2+k3.^2);
k30 = k3 + beta.*k1;
k0 = sqrt(k1.^2+k2.^2+k30.^2);
E_k0 = 1.453.*(k0.^4./((1+k0.^2).^(17/6)));
```

Therefore the expression for phi_33 would result in

```
phi_33 = (E_k0./(4*pi.*(k.^4))).*(k1.^2+k2.^2);
```

The question is: how can I make use of this final expression insted of the long one I'm using at the moment (within the for loop)?

The last expression for phi_33 is easier to handle (especially because of reckless mistakes in writing the former) and it would "pass by reference" (k2,k3), which are the independent variables.

Any hint is more than welcome.

Best regards,
fpe

Comment: The question will be more readable if you could distill the essence of what you are asking about, and only that. I couldn't understand if you just wanted to vectorize your code or not?

Comment: What is the value of `E_int(400)`?

Comment: @natan I don't wanna vectorize. I want the handle function within the for loop to use the last expression of phi_33 and not that extended one I'm using at the moment.

Comment: @Shai: I'm just following what's written in a scientific paper; I made myself the same question, but as long as my results match thos on the paper I'm OK. (not that rigorous but ready-to-use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to use the new expression in exactly the same way as the old one-liner. You just want to divide your function `phi33` into parts because of readability.

You could do this by placing the expression in a separate function taking all values needed for the calculation. Using your old expression exactly this would look something like this:

```
function phi_33 = phi_33_old(k1,k2,k3,beta,i)

phi_33 = (1.453./(4.*pi)).*(((k1(i)^2+k2.^2+(k3 + beta(i).*k1(i)).^2).^2)./((k1(i)^2+k2.^2+k3.^2).^2)).*((k1(i)^2+k2.^2)./((1+k1(i)^2+k2.^2+(k3+beta(i).*k1(i)).^2).^(17/6)));

end
```

This function could then be called inside your for-loop like this.

```
phi_33_test = @(k2,k3) phi_33_old(k1,k2,k3,beta,i);
```

Using the same style, a new function could be defined as follows.

```
function phi_33 = phi_33_new(k1,k2,k3,beta,i)

k = sqrt(k1.^2+k2.^2+k3.^2);
k30 = k3 + beta.*k1;
k0 = sqrt(k1.^2+k2.^2+k30.^2);
E_k0 = 1.453.*(k0.^4./((1+k0.^2).^(17/6)));
phi_33_allValues = (E_k0./(4*pi.*(k.^4))).*(k1.^2+k2.^2);
phi_33 = phi_33_allValues(i);

end
```

Note that here all values of `phi_33` are calculated and then the `i`th value is selected. It is written in this way only to show the similarity to the old case. This new function can now be called inside the for-loop in the same way as the old one.

```
phi_33 = @(k2,k3) phi_33_new(k1,k2,k3,beta,i);
```

Comment: this hint should be what I was looking for. I'll work on it. Thanks a lot

Comment: I edited your answer with the approach leading to the results I need to match by making use of the phi_33_new function. It works